# How to count number of files in a file with certain extension or name?

Tags: python, count, counting

My problem is I want to make a list of how many files with a certain extension or names in a folder when there are a lot of different types of files in it.

For instance, let's say there are a bunch of different types of files in a folder and I only want to count how many jpg files there are.

I tried the code below from some other person's Q&A on stackoverflow and it does show all the names of jpg files in the folder but doesn't show the number of how many jpg files there are.

```
import glob, os
filelist = os.listdir('D:\Train')
for file in filelist:
    if(file.endswith('jpg')):
        print(file)
```

Also, I'd like to know if there's a way I can count the file with certain words in the names.
ex) count all the jpg files in the folder that contain 'fire' in their names (`fire01.jpg`, `fire02.jpg`, and so on)

Comment: Glob https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, as indicated in the earlier answer, `len(glob.glob(...))` will tell you how many files matched the glob if you can rearticulate your requirement into a single wildcard pattern.

In the general case (for example, if you want to match `.png`, `.jpeg`,  `.JPEG`, etc), just increment a variable each time you see an occurrence.

```
# Stylistic fix: don't combine imports
import glob
import os

# This is our counter
count = 0

# Notice r'' raw string to preserve literal backslash
for file in os.listdir(r'D:\Train'):
    if(file.endswith('jpg')):
        print(file)
        count += 1

print('Total:', count)
```

You can add a second variable `fire_count` too; maybe then also rename the original variable for consistency.

```
total_count = 0
fire_count = 0

for file in os.listdir(r'D:\Train'):
    if(file.endswith('jpg')):
        print(file)
        total_count += 1
        if 'fire' in file:
            fire_count += 1

print('Total:', total_count)
print('Fire files:', fire_count)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use glob like this example

```
import glob, os
filelist = glob.glob('D:\Train\*.jpg')
print(len(filelist))
for file in filelist:
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

SO, I have three files, file1.pdf, file2.pdf, and file3.pdf in my path /tmp/test-dir

You can use below code to get total count of pdf files.

```
import glob
path_to_check = "/tmp/test-dir/"
total_txt_files = len(glob.glob1(path_to_check,"*.pdf"))
print(total_txt_files)
```

## Output

3

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the os.listdir()-function, which returns a list of all filenames in a given directory, like in this example:

```
import os
print(len(os.listdir('D:\\Train\\'))
```

Since you are only interested in files that end in images, you can add a comprehension list and only keep files that end with '.jpg'

```
print(len([x for x in os.listdir('D:\\Train\\') if x[-4:] == '.jpg']))
```

Comment: print(len([x for x in os.listdir(PATH_SCREEN) if x[-4:] == '.jpg']))