# Parse filenames and make a total count of occurances of the first two words, over 50K names

Tags: python, parsing, filenames, counting

I wanted to make a count of the total number of filenames that had the same 2 unique words in the start of the filename (tree names or other identifier), and iterate through the whole folder (over 50K files), recording those names and give individual and overall totals for the occurances.

The filenames look something like this, or variations thereof:

```
Abies_alba_0_2545_WEFL_NLF.tif
Abies_alba_8_321565_WEFL_NLF.tif
Larix_kaempferi_3_43357_WEFL_NLF.tif
```

I actually managed a workaround and got the results that I wanted - but this was very slow for me to manually capture the key parts of the string, and manually repeat the script. I used [How to count number of files in a file with certain extension or name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113299) as a basis and produced this:

```
import glob
import os

# These are our counters
total_count = 0
Abies_alba_count = 0
Acer_pseudoplatanus_count = 0
Alnus_spec_count = 0
Betula_spec_count = 0
Cleared_0_count = 0
Fagus_sylvatica_count = 0
Fraxinus_excelsior_count = 0
Larix_decidua_count = 0
Larix_kaempferi_count = 0
Picea_abies_count = 0 
Pinus_nigra_count = 0
Pinus_strobus_count = 0 
Pinus_sylvestris_count = 0
Populus_spec_count = 0
Prunus_spec_count = 0
Pseudotsuga_menziesii_count = 0
Quercus_petraea_count = 0
Quercus_robur_count = 0
Quercus_rubra_count = 0
Tilia_spec_count = 0


for file in 
    os.listdir(r'FILEPATH TO FOLDER HOLDING THE FILES'):
    if(file.endswith('tif')):
        total_count += 1
        if 'Abies_alba' in file:
            Abies_alba_count += 1
        if 'Acer_pseudoplatanus' in file:
            Acer_pseudoplatanus_count += 1
        if 'Alnus_spec' in file:
            Alnus_spec_count += 1
        if 'Betula_spec' in file:
            Betula_spec_count += 1
        if 'Cleared_0' in file:
            Cleared_0_count += 1
        if 'Fagus_sylvatica' in file:
            Fagus_sylvatica_count += 1
        if 'Fraxinus_excelsior' in file:
            Fraxinus_excelsior_count += 1
        if 'Larix_decidua' in file:
            Larix_decidua_count += 1
        if 'Larix_kaempferi' in file:
            Larix_kaempferi_count += 1
        if 'Picea_abies' in file:
            Picea_abies_count += 1
        if 'Pinus_nigra' in file:
            Pinus_nigra_count += 1
        if 'Pinus_strobus' in file:
            Pinus_strobus_count += 1
        if 'Pinus_sylvestris' in file:
            Pinus_sylvestris_count += 1
        if 'Populus_spec' in file:
            Populus_spec_count += 1
        if 'Prunus_spec' in file:
            Prunus_spec_count += 1
        if 'Pseudotsuga_menziesii' in file:
            Pseudotsuga_menziesii_count += 1
        if 'Quercus_petraea' in file:
            Quercus_petraea_count += 1
        if 'Quercus_robur' in file:
            Quercus_robur_count += 1
        if 'Quercus_rubra' in file:
            Quercus_rubra_count += 1
        if 'Tilia_spec' in file:
            Tilia_spec_count += 1

print('Abies alba:', Abies_alba_count)
print('Acer pseudoplatanus:', Acer_pseudoplatanus_count)
print('Alnus spec:', Alnus_spec_count)
print('Betula_spec:', Betula_spec_count)
print('Cleared 0:', Cleared_0_count)
print('Fagus sylvatica:', Fagus_sylvatica_count)
print('Fraxinus excelsior:', Fraxinus_excelsior_count)
print('Larix decidua:', Larix_decidua_count)
print('Larix kaempferi:', Larix_kaempferi_count)
print('Picea abies:', Picea_abies_count)
print('Pinus nigra:', Pinus_nigra_count)
print('Pinus strobus:', Pinus_strobus_count)
print('Pinus sylvestris:', Pinus_sylvestris_count)
print('Populus spec:', Populus_spec_count)
print('Prunus spec:', Prunus_spec_count)
print('Pseudotsuga menziesii:', Pseudotsuga_menziesii_count)
print('Quercus petraea:', Quercus_petraea_count)
print('Quercus robur:', Quercus_robur_count)
print('Quercus rubra:', Quercus_rubra_count)
print('Tilia spec:', Tilia_spec_count)
print('Total:', total_count)
```

Which works and gives me the results I wanted, as below:

```
Abies alba: 984
Acer pseudoplatanus: 2821
Alnus spec: 2563
Betula_spec: 2821
Cleared 0: 4123
Fagus sylvatica: 6459
Fraxinus excelsior: 2634
Larix decidua: 1360
Larix kaempferi: 1748
Picea abies: 5783
Pinus nigra: 421
Pinus strobus: 500
Pinus sylvestris: 6591
Populus spec: 464
Prunus spec: 304
Pseudotsuga menziesii: 2691
Quercus petraea: 2608
Quercus robur: 3453
Quercus rubra: 1841
Tilia spec: 212
Total: 50381
```

So, yes, this works but was awful to do and I understand to be smelly code if Im using the term correctly! Could someone advise on how to get to the end result without all the manual interference that I had to do?

I intend to also plot the output in some follow up work, showing the number weighting of the  file/tree types, but was trying to avoid writing to a CSV and working the results from there as I understand that to be bad practice. Any further tips for this?

Comment: Use [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for code reviews — not stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Im not a regular user and wasnt aware of the other forum but I'll try to follow your lead in future. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
import os
file_names = os.listdir('YOUR_DIRECTORY')
file_counts = {}
for filename in file_names:
  if filename.endswith('tif'):
    filename_parts = filename.split('_')
    key = filename_parts[0] + '_' + filename_parts[1]
    if key in file_counts.keys():
      file_counts[key] += 1
    else:
      file_counts[key] = 1

print(file_counts)
```

Comment: Thanks @gordanvij, Ill give this a run and see how I get on

Comment: @gordannvij - thanks this appraoch works as is and poroducues the output as expected. There There are a couple of things for me to tidy up eg removing underscorein the string, but this does what is needed. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary! Updated to dynamically determine the words to search.

```
words = set()
counts = {}
total_count = 0
file_names = os.listdir(r'FILEPATH TO FOLDER HOLDING THE FILES')
for file_name in file_names:
    fn_words = file_name.split("_")
    words.add(f"{fn_words[0]} {fn_words[1]}")
for word in words:
    for file_name in file_names:
        if word in file_name and word in counts: 
            counts[word] += 1
            total_count += 1
        elif word in file_name: 
            counts[word] = 1
            total_count += 1
[print(f"{word}: {count}" for word, count in counts.items()] ### You could iterate through this dict in any way if you would rather process the data in some other fashion than just printing.
print(f"Total: {total_count}")
```

Comment: You don't have to statically keep the word combinations in the dictionary. It can be figured out, by looking at the available dictionary keys, while you iterate through the words and update the counts accordingly in dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Jesse, I think thats a useful approach, but part of the issue that I was trying to avoid is my knowing what the first two words in the string were because I had to scroll through the 50K files and work that out manually! I think your approach keeps me doing that. I suppose another way of asking is there a way to parse the first 2 words out of the filename then count how often they appear?

Comment: @10B I have updated my answer to parse the unique two word filename starts dynamically - storing them in a set guarantees each two word combination will only be stored once.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks - this looks more like what I need which is great, but it keeps falling over at this:
  words.add(f"{fn_words[0]} {fn_words[1]}")
saying "list index out of range". 

Ive tried to change the range but this has no improvemnt unfortunatley. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @10B I think the issue is that I initially just used file_name.split() - I have updated it to use file_name.split("_") after realising your file names are delimited by underscores, that should fix the issue

Comment: @Jesse Thanks again for the input, but Im sorry to say it is still running into the same issue (index out of range) following the underscore update. I think I understand the approach you are using, but I just cannot seem to make it work!